# I want the user to be able to download a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the code,

```
    string loadFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    // this.Response.ClearContent();
    // this.Response.ClearHeaders();
    this.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename " + filename);
    this.Response.ContentType ="application/html";

    this.Response.WriteFile("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Jobspoint Website\\jobpoint3.0\\print.aspx");
    this.Response.Flush();
    this.Response.Close();
    this.Response.End();
```

to download an aspx page in asp.net C#.. But its only showing the html tags and static values... How can I save the entire page without html tags and with the values that retrieved from the database?
Thanks...
Leema

Comment: Do you mean, you want to scrape the HTML for some data and save it somewhere?

Comment: It sounds like you want the user to save the resultant markup from the webforms page. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, but its saving only the values which i typed manually not the database values and any textboxes, labels or other controls..

Answer (score 5):

Use [WebClient](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial66_Using-WebClient-to-download-a-file.html) for this. It will download your file.

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood correctly, one option would be to actually make a request to the web server using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) for example. And then write the response to that request to the [Response.OutputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx). This means that the server will actually make a second request to it self and then send the response to the second request back to the client.

This way you will have the web server actually process the request and return the resulting HTML back to you rather than just the raw `aspx` page.